Map the values from an NgForm to a typescript model defined in Angular
I'm looking for the most efficient way to map values from an NgForm to a typescript model defined in my Angular component. The form values are coming from a datatable (p-table using PrimeNG) with varying rows. I'm getting the values defined in a JSON object. I have appended the row index to the end of each form control name (- rowIndex).
For example:
{
"controlA-0" : 123, "controlB-0" : 456, "controlC-0" : 789,
"controlA-1" : 321, "controlB-1" : 654, "controlC-1" : 987
"controlA-2" : 213, "controlB-2" : 564, "controlC-2" : 897
}

Here is my real JSON object from the NgForm (newOperationalAreaForm). The example form below has four (4) rows (counties) for the state of Hawaii in the p-table. Other forms (Different states) will have varying row counts depending on the number of counties in the selected state.
{
    "AreaOfOperationId-0": 0,
    "StateCountyLookupID-0": 544,
    "StateId-0": "12",
    "StateCode-0": "HI",
    "StateDisplayName-0": "Hawaii",
    "CountyId-0": "711",
    "CountyDisplayName-0": "Hawaii",
    "county-primary-0": true,
    "county-secondary-0": false,
    "county-na-0": false,
    "AreaOfOperationId-1": 0,
    "StateCountyLookupID-1": 545,
    "StateId-1": "12",
    "StateCode-1": "HI",
    "StateDisplayName-1": "Hawaii",
    "CountyId-1": "743",
    "CountyDisplayName-1": "Honolulu",
    "county-primary-1": false,
    "county-secondary-1": true,
    "county-na-1": false,
    "AreaOfOperationId-2": 0,
    "StateCountyLookupID-2": 546,
    "StateId-2": "12",
    "StateCode-2": "HI",
    "StateDisplayName-2": "Hawaii",
    "CountyId-2": "826",
    "CountyDisplayName-2": "Kauai",
    "county-primary-2": true,
    "county-secondary-2": false,
    "county-na-2": false,
    "AreaOfOperationId-3": 0,
    "StateCountyLookupID-3": 547,
    "StateId-3": "12",
    "StateCode-3": "HI",
    "StateDisplayName-3": "Hawaii",
    "CountyId-3": "996",
    "CountyDisplayName-3": "Maui",
    "county-primary-3": false,
    "county-secondary-3": false,
    "county-na-3": true
}

Here is the model defined in typescript that I need to map the NgForm to:
newOperationalArea= {
    AreaOfOperationId: number,
    StateCountyLookupID: number,
    State: {
      Id: string,
      Code: string,
      DisplayName: string
    },
    County: {
      Id: string,
      DisplayName: string,
    },
    county-primary: boolean,
    county-secondary: boolean,
    county-na: boolean,
  }


I tried using this code to get each control and the value but the values displayed in the console didn't produce the values that I need to submit the object to my web api.
Object.values(newOperationalAreaForm.controls).forEach( ctl => {
   console.log(ctl);
})

Here's the object I'm expecting to send to my web api put method:
"AreaOfOperation ="[
   {
      "AreaOfOperationId":0,
      "StateCountyLookupID":544,
      "State":{
         "Id":"12",
         "Code":"HI",
         "DisplayName":"Hawaii"
      },
      "County":{
         "Id":"711",
         "DisplayName":"Hawaii"
      },
      "county-primary":true,
      "county-secondary":false,
      "county-na":false
   },
   {
      "AreaOfOperationId":0,
      "StateCountyLookupID":545,
      "State":{
         "Id":"12",
         "Code":"HI",
         "DisplayName":"Hawaii"
      },
      "County":{
         "Id":"743",
         "DisplayName":"Honolulu"
      },
      "county-primary":false,
      "county-secondary":true,
      "county-na":false
   },
   {
      "AreaOfOperationId":0,
      "StateCountyLookupID":546,
      "State":{
         "Id":"12",
         "Code":"HI",
         "DisplayName":"Hawaii"
      },
      "County":{
         "Id":"826",
         "DisplayName":"Kauai"
      },
      "county-primary":true,
      "county-secondary":false,
      "county-na":false
   },
   {
      "AreaOfOperationId":0,
      "StateCountyLookupID":547,
      "State":{
         "Id":"12",
         "Code":"HI",
         "DisplayName":"Hawaii"
      },
      "County":{
         "Id":"996",
         "DisplayName":"Maui"
      },
      "county-primary":false,
      "county-secondary":false,
      "county-na":false
   }
]


please share the original data that you want to map to a form, also if possible a stackblitz

@NarenMurali, thanks for your reply. I will try and put a stackblitz together. The original data is retrieved from web api get method using the typescript data model(see below).
newOperationalArea= {
AreaOfOperationId: number,
StateCountyLookupID: number,
State: {
Id: string,
Code: string,
DisplayName: string
},
County: {
Id: string,
DisplayName: string,
},
county-primary: boolean,
county-secondary: boolean,
county-na: boolean,
}
I then apply the original data model from Get to the NgForm elements => JSON

Let me get this straight. You want to display a line from a p-data-table correctly in a form and want to convert it into a typescript model defined by you?
Use form.getRawValues( ) to get only values?
//Updated:
export interface Data {
  controlA: number;
  controlB: number;
  controlC: number;
}

const DATAKEYS = ['controlA', 'controlB', 'controlC'];

@Component(...)
export class Component implements OnInit {
  private readonly json_data = {
    'controlA-0': 123,
    'controlB-0': 456,
    'controlC-0': 789,
    'controlA-1': 321,
    'controlB-1': 654,
    'controlC-1': 987,
    'controlA-2': 213,
    'controlB-2': 564,
    'controlC-2': 897,
  };

  private readonly result: Data[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    const items = 3;

    for (let i = 0; i < items; i++) {
      const data: Data = { controlA: 0, controlB: 0, controlC: 0 };

      DATAKEYS.forEach((key) => {
        const value =
          this.json_data[`${key}-${i}` as keyof typeof this.json_data];
        data[key as keyof Data] = value;
      });

      this.result.push(data);
    }
  }
}


@Marion, Hi thank you for your reply. No, I'm displaying the lines correctly in the p-table correctly. It is when I'm submitting the form, I need to map all of the form values from NgForm (newOperationalAreaForm.values) to the Typescript model (newOperationalArea) to create an array of objects of type . When I click submit for the State of Hawaii, I will have four objects of type  coming from the newOperationalAreaForm.values. I know it will be four objects for Hawaii because there are four counties for Hawaii. From my JSON object I need to map each row

@Marion, In the Submit Function, I'm getting the NgForm Values with the rowIndex appended to the control name ( - 0 for 1st row items, -1 for 2nd row items, -2 for 3rd row items and -3 for 4th row items). From JSON object listed in my original post, I need to map all 1st row items (-0) to the typescript model of type 
"StateCountyLookupID-0": 544, will get mapped to 1st object =>     "StateCountyLookupID" : 544,
"StateCountyLookupID-1": 545,  will get mapped to 2nd object => "StateCountyLookupID" : 545,
"StateCountyLookupID-2": 546, => 3rd object etc.

@JeffO'Connell i updeted my post

@Marion, this does the trick! Thank you very much!

@JeffO'Connell thats nice! It was a pleasure
